# Facebook comments not working on Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-comments

I added Facebook Comment Box to my site manually. I created an app and pasted the code on my template files.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '730627806953221',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then I added this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="430" style="max-width: 100%;"></div>
```

It seems to work, when a user comments it displays correctly. However when I try to reply to someone who left a comment it doesn´t stay there. I´m trying to reply as a brand not as myself.

Why could this be?